# show a subset generates a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

How would I show that the subset $V = \{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)\}$ generates the symmetric group $S_4$?

I am just being introduced to group theory this is all new. I have unsuccessfully attempted to solve this question. . How do you prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

Here is a hint:

We know that every permutation can be written as a product of transpositions
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953960/permutation-written-as-product-of-transpositions), for instance). So if you can get every transposition, then you can get every permutation (do you see why?).

Of course, you already have $3$ transpositions available! Can you combine these to get the others?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the transpositions from those three.  There are ${4\choose2}=6$ transpositions total, so there are sort of $3$ things to check.

For instance, $(12)(23)(12)=(13)$.

(One more hint:  the conjugation action is transitive;  that is all the transpositions are conjugate)

So it remains to find $(14)$ and $(24)$.

Comment: okay so ive attempted and so far, I have (13)=(12)(23)(12) and (14)=(13)(34)(13) ? not too confident though

Comment: To finish, note that $(24)=(12)(14)(12)$.

Comment: so If I explain this correctly with the transpositions found, it can be said that all are conjugate like you mentioned thus if we were to form a matrix it would generate all elements of S4?

Comment: Well, as was pointed out in the other answer, all the permutations can be written as a product of transpositions.  I just mentioned conjugacy to help you along.